# Android emulator won't start with Hyper-V & Hypervisor platform

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, emulation, hyper-v

I have problem with my Android emulator. I have Intel i7-10610U CPU which supports all required virtualization etc. but unfortunately I cannot install HAXM beause of group policy which requires for Hyper-V to be running.

According to [Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration) and [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows) I should be able to use hardware acceleration with Hyper-V and WHPX (Windows Hypervisor Platform).
I did all the required steps from above tuorials. I have Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platorm installed (also tried reinstalling them):
[windows features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J93oj.png)
I also have virtualization enabled:
[virtualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZOae.png)

When I try to run emulator I have a message

> VERBOSE | Checking whether Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is available.
> VERBOSE | WinHvPlatform.dll found. Looking for WHvGetCapability...
> VERBOSE | WHvGetCapability found. Querying WHPX capabilities...
> VERBOSE | WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0
>
> VERBOSE | WHPX is either not available or not installed.
> VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
> VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: Hyper-V detected and Windows Hypervisor Platform is available. Please ensure both the "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Platform" features enabled in "Turn Windows features on or off".

It seems that Android emulator is requesting WHvGetCapability and it fails?
There are only few issues like this on the web but with no answers. Please help!